# Error when using AdView constructor for Facebook Ads

Tags: android, facebook-ads-api

I want to use Facebook Ads in my android app .
It gives me an error in `AdView` constructor . The error is `Expected parameters Actual Arguments` .

Here is my code

in xml

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/banner_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    />
```

In `mainActivity`

```
com.facebook.ads.AdView adView2 = new AdView(this, "my ID",AdSize.BANNER_HEIGHT_50);
    LinearLayout adContainer = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.banner_container);
    adContainer.addView(adView2);
    adView2.loadAd();
```

In build.app

```
    compile 'com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:4.18.0'
```

Comment: Where are you having this code exactly . can you post the whole method .

Comment: This code in `OnCreate() ` method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you have messed up with  `import` . Make sure the import.

```
import com.facebook.ads.AdSize;
import com.facebook.ads.AdView;

 AdView adView2 = new AdView(this, "my ID", AdSize.BANNER_HEIGHT_50);
```

Or you can use fully qualified name for it  .

```
com.facebook.ads.AdView adView2 = new com.facebook.ads.AdView(this, "my ID", com.facebook.ads.AdSize.BANNER_HEIGHT_50);
```

Comment: Thank you It works . But have you an idea why the ad doesn't appear ?

Comment: This you have check on [Documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/audience-network/android-native) . Make sure the the credentials and settings are right .Good luck